# How can I make a box like product packet?

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view, packed-data

I need to design 3D model something like packet of product with just 2-3 sides. I have images for front face and back face of a packet. I just need to assign images only and no shadow or anything fancy required. Just a basic product model we need which have 3 sides and need to assign textures on 2 side (3rd is bottom side which is never going to be shown to user because it is on surface).

I have created cube type of objects with UV mapping texture on it, but for this object, there are not flat sides, it has curves.

How can I achieve this in blender?

> Here is what kind of object I need:

[image]

> Here is Front side texture image

[image]

> Here is Back side texture image

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you just need to create some Seams before you unwrap. Then, once you have unwrapped, the two sides will be individual UV islands and you can set you images to appear in the correct place.

Comment: I can make straight seam but in this case, I will have to give curves to the sides. Also merge top to sides into one

Comment: You can also use the UV Project from View and set the view to be the Front for one UV and the Back for a second UV. Then select them as independent input Nodes when setting up the material in Node editor.

Comment: Do you have any sample created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Base material. I just used a **Diffuse BSDF** Orange.

[image: set the base material]

Load up your image for the front of the packet. I used the a Color Grid generated in Blender.

[image: image editor]

Select required faces and **Unwrap**. I deliberately left a border so you can see the base material. This will create a default **UV Map**

[image: select and unwrap]

Set up material **Nodes** to start with and **Input->UV Map** set to the default map connected to an **Texture->Image** with your image. Make sure it is set to **Clip** then take that through a **Diffuse BSDF Shader** and **Mix** it with the Base.

[image: setup the shading]

Now add a new **UV Map** and select the next faces and **Unwrap**

[image: unwrap part two]

Now you can duplicate your existing **Nodes** and change the **UV Map input** and use a **Mix Shader** to combine them. I have used the same image but you can choose a different source image for the back.

[image: nodes part two]

Just to show how you can manipulate the unwrapped island. Scaled and rotated.

[image: unwrap manipulated]

Commonly and especially for games, people will use a single image and unwrap to a part of it. I find multiple UVMaps gives me more control.

[image: final product]

Comment: This is such a detailed answer I never expected from Stack Exchange. Thanks for giving your time. I will be following this tutorial once I get free.

Comment: Can you share .blend file if you don't mind?

Comment: I don't know how to prepare base material (from the default cube)

Comment: here you go https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6584/

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob, how can I reduce the width of a packet, i.e. width of the portion which comes outside

Comment: not sure what you mean. You can use the standard Blender Scale tool and change X,Y,Z independently or together.

Comment: Width of a stomach I am talking Rob

Comment: And secondly I need to change front and back images of my product...else is great Rob

Comment: I have reduced with Rob, I just needed to reduce z scale and now, it fits for my product.. now I am trying to change UV map images

Comment: I tried but I am not able to change the UV map image..

Comment: Have a look at some Blender tutorials for UV unwrapping. But it should be really simple to substitute the Texture image in the Node editor.

Comment: I have an issue while selecting faces and Unwrap object. It repeats textures and each face is render with full image.. basically I want to select all faces rather than you left few faces.So, I remove UVMap in your sample and add new to select all..

Comment: Following the instructions you can create as many UV maps as you want even ones that overlap or are all faces at once. Then it is just a matter of setting the factor in the Mix Shader/s for which ones to show. For the repeating image issue make sure the Image Texture is set to Clip, the default is Repeat.

Comment: Done Rob, I was unwrapping in face section rather than point section and everything worked like a charm. One more thing I would like to learn is how can I change the dimensions of a packet object i.e. rounded corners, mode wide from top and less from bottom etc..

Comment: This would be basic Mesh editing. Start with Scaling and constraining the Scaling action to X, Y or Z. If you need more control then in Edit mode for the Mesh you can manually move the vertices, look at Proportional Editing.

Comment: Thanks Rob, I will check it. I have learnt a lot from your answer and achieved what I needed.